# Setting Bit from Dynamic Array and Then Displaying it

Tags: c++, set, overloading, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a Constructor that creates a BitArray object, which asks a user for how many 'bits' they would like to use. It then uses unsigned chars to store the Bytes needed to hold the many. I then wish to create methods that allow for a user to 'Set' a certain bit, and also to Display the full set of Bytes at the end. However, my Set method does not seem to be changing the bit, that, or my Print function (The Overload) does not seem to actually be printing the actual bit(s). Can somebody point out the problem please?

Constructor

```
BitArray::BitArray(unsigned int n)
{

//Now let's find the minimum 'bits' needed

n++;
//If it does not "perfectly" fit
//------------------------------------ehhhh
if( (n % BYTE) != 0)
    arraySize =(n / BYTE);
else
    arraySize = (n / BYTE) + 1;

//Now dynamically create the array with full byte size
barray = new unsigned char[arraySize];

//Now intialize bytes to 0
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    barray[i] = (int) 0;
}

}
```

Set Method:

```
    void BitArray::Set(unsigned int index)
{
        //Set the Indexed Bit to ON
        barray[index/BYTE] |= 0x01 << (index%BYTE);
}
```

Print Overload:

```
 ostream &operator<<(ostream& os, const BitArray& a)
{  
        for(int i = 0; i < (a.Length()*BYTE+1); i++)
        {
            int curNum = i/BYTE;
            char charToPrint = a.barray[curNum];
            os << (charToPrint & 0X01);
            charToPrint >>= 1;
        }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused.. but it looks like you're using a `char[]` array to hold individual 'bit' values in each index. If that's the case.. your `Set` function should simply be: `barray[index - 1] = '1';`? No shifting is needed if each `char` in the array holds 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < (a.Length()*BYTE+1); i++)
    {
        int curNum = i/BYTE;
        char charToPrint = a.barray[curNum];
        os << (charToPrint & 0X01);
        charToPrint >>= 1;
    }
```

Each time you run your loop, you are fetching a new value for `charToPrint`. That means that the operation `charToPrint >>= 1;` is useless, since that modification is not going to be carried out to the next time the loop runs. Therefore, you will always print only the first bit of each `char` of your array.